# AutoMapper index out of bounds exception in MappingEngine.cs

Tags: c#, exception, automapper

Currently we are running AutoMapper 1.0.1.156 in production on a WCF webservice and after about a week or so we will start to get the following error (note this was also happening in 0.4.0.126 but we couldn't get a stack trace because we only had the .dll from codeplex and no .pdb):

> Trying to map DataAccess.Call to DataTypes.Call.
>   Using mapping configuration for DataAccess.Call to DataTypes.Call
>   Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.
>   at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context) in C:\Work\AutoMapper\src\AutoMapper\MappingEngine.cs:line 154
>   at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(Object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType) in C:\Work\AutoMapper\src\AutoMapper\MappingEngine.cs:line 104
>   at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source) in C:\Work\AutoMapper\src\AutoMapper\MappingEngine.cs:line 34
>   at AutoMapper.Mapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source) in C:\Work\AutoMapper\src\AutoMapper\Mapper.cs:line 21

Here is the mapping configuration for the Map being executed when the error happens:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DataAccess.Call, DataTypes.Call>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CallTypeId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CallType))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CallType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (DataTypes.CallType)src.CallType));
```

The code runs find for about a week or so with no errors. Once we start getting errors, if we recycle the application pool for the WCF webservice, the error goes away.

I have double checked, triple checked, and rechecked that src.CallType can not possibly contain any values which are not in the enum DataTypes.CallType.

The class/enum definitions are at http://pastebin.com/2pF0gFZ2

Searched all over and couldn't find anybody else having this issue.

Comment: Is there any more stack trace you have, in the inner exceptions?

Comment: The exception after that point in the stack trace is the non-AutoMapper portion but I can post it if you like.

Comment: Is there an inner exception?  The reason why I ask is the exception at that point is a catch-wrap-throw piece.  There should be an inner exception with more info (type map not found, etc.)

Comment: Hi Jimmy, 

I have exact same situation as Nate. We are using 0.4,xx in PROD with a WCF service.
This error seems to happen after a while the server is active, once recycled the problem disappears. 

Here is my inner exception. 
http://pastebin.com/BuqGipfa

Any ideas are  greatly appreciated, sorry to hijack this thread.

Comment: Was there any resolution to this? - a having the same problem

Comment: @user1069733 Not to my knowledge. For our case we were using it to do pretty simple object translations, so we ditched AutoMapper and just wrote methods to map one object to another.